# IIS7 server wide custom errors

Tags: iis, iis-7

I am wondering if it's possible to establish server wide custom errors in IIS7.  I am not concerned about the custom errors at the application level, this task is complete.

The scenario is someone requests a page from my application, but the application is down, but the server is still live.  Obviously, my application custom errors can't be executed, but can I specify a custom 404 at the server level?

Do you have any steps or tutorials to establish this task?

Thank you,

Roka

Comment: What do you mean by "server is down"? Hardware failure?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that my application is down for some reason, but the server is still live.

Comment: then you also need to define what is "my application is down". There are tons of cases and no silver bullet for all.